# Query params getting removed after page load in angular?

Tags: angular, url-routing

I have an angular app and when I add query params(in the search bar by hand) in the URL they are removed after the app load.

For example, `https://app.com/login?param=1` becomes `https://app.com/login`.

And I do not know why this happens, if I check the network tab the params are sent to the server.

I have put the following code in the `main.ts` file
`console.log(window.location.search)` it shows correctly the params, but after the router matches the url and renders the component they get removed and `ActivatedRoute` queryParams are empty.

Any advice would be helpful. I am using angular 13.0.0

Comment: Any redirects in your routing or maybe an interceptor that navigates?

Comment: Thank you!!!!!. It was a guard that was doing a redirect.

Comment: Cool. Glad you solved it!

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you have some path like "/login" somewhere in some of your routing modules?

Probably, you are managing it "as it is", I mean, just like "/login", for instance:

```
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full',
},
```

Maybe, you should treat it as it was waiting for a parameter, something like this:

```
{ path: 'login/:id', component: LoginComponent }
```

and getting the parameter in LoginComponent with something like this:

```
    if (this.route.snapshot.params.id) {
      const param = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
    }
```

Or better, subscribing to the change paremeters:

```
this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe((params) => {
      let param =  = params.get('id');
    });
```

That would work with 'https://app.com/login?1', and the 1 would be saved in the "param" variable of your code.